# Problems setting up own Cloud Lab

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, wlan, cloud

I'm trying to set up an own Cloud Lab on a self-built server.

Server details:

- Board: Gigabyte Z77MX-D3H TH
- CPU: Xeon E3-1245 v2
- 16GB Crucial Ballistix CL8 1600Mhz
- NETWORK: ALFA AWUS036H
- additional crap (like crap-hdd, cooler, etc).

I can only use (at this moment) a wireless connection because the box is far away from the router.

I tried with Cloudstack and wanted to try with Openstack but I have read a lot of about (people who work with in production) that it is not a good solution and it will be more useful for me to try out with ProxMox.

Now I have ProxMox up, but I can not establish any wireless-connections. At the PVE-Forum I got that they don't support or have not provided any wireless-network setup because PVE has some problems because of bridging.

**My question is now:**

I have my metal here (see hardware description above).
I have almost no experience with virtualization on Unix/Linux.
(I'm using VMware WS on my Ubuntu and I worked some weeks with OpenNebula (setting up and s.o.).
-> What should I use for my Cloud Lab / virtualisation environment, and if ProxMox is a good point to go on, how to solve the wireless problem?

**EDIT:**

I will definitely need kvm as hypervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use devstack. Have a look at the instructions here:
http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html

Comment: will try it out later. seems to be interesting. as temporary solution I'm with vmware now.

Comment: Note that you can set up devstack to use vSphere as the virtualization engine: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NovaVMware/DeveloperGuide

Comment: ok, thanks. I work with vmware workstation as temporary solution because I have to setup a lot. But vSphere seems to be very interesting.